# Wagtail API not exposing custom field

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, wagtail, wagtail-apiv2

I am enabling wagtail api v2 in my wagtail project. After adding the api.v2 I am getting this json response

```
    {
        "id": 32,
        "meta": {
            "type": "blog.AddStory",
            "detail_url": "http://localhost/api/v2/pages/32/",
            "html_url": "http://localhost/blog/1st-story/",
            "slug": "1st-story",
            "first_published_at": "2022-07-19T18:06:50.205210Z"
        },
        "title": "1st story"
    }
```

I want to add my `content` field after `title` field. I added this in my `models.py` file

```
from wagtail.api import APIField
from rest_framework import serializers
#Exposing Custom Page Fields/content
api_fileds = [
  APIField('content'),
  APIField('custom_title'),
  APIField('blog_image'),
]
```

Here is my `api.py` file

```
from wagtail.api.v2.views import PagesAPIViewSet
from wagtail.api.v2.router import WagtailAPIRouter
from wagtail.images.api.v2.views import ImagesAPIViewSet
from wagtail.documents.api.v2.views import DocumentsAPIViewSet

api_router = WagtailAPIRouter('wagtailapi')

api_router.register_endpoint('pages', PagesAPIViewSet)
api_router.register_endpoint('images', ImagesAPIViewSet)
api_router.register_endpoint('documents', DocumentsAPIViewSet)
```

Why it's not exposing custom fields? Here is my full `models.py` file

```
"""Blog listing and blog detail pages."""
from django.db import models
from modelcluster.fields import ParentalManyToManyField
from django import forms
from wagtail.admin.edit_handlers import FieldPanel, StreamFieldPanel, MultiFieldPanel,InlinePanel
from wagtail.core.fields import StreamField
#Api Section import
from wagtail.api import APIField
from rest_framework import serializers

from wagtail.images.edit_handlers import ImageChooserPanel

from wagtail.core.models import Page
from wagtail.snippets.models import register_snippet

from . import blocks
from .blocks import InlineVideoBlock

from modelcluster.fields import ParentalKey
from modelcluster.contrib.taggit import ClusterTaggableManager
from taggit.models import TaggedItemBase


@register_snippet
class BlogCategory(models.Model):
    """Blog category for a snippet."""

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField(
        verbose_name="slug",
        allow_unicode=True,
        max_length=255,
        help_text='A slug to identify posts by this category',
    )

    panels = [
        FieldPanel("name"),
        FieldPanel("slug"),
    ]

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Blog Category"
        verbose_name_plural = "Blog Categories"
        ordering = ["name"]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class CreateNewPage(Page):
    """Listing page lists all the Blog Detail Pages."""

    # template = "blog/create_new_page.html"

    custom_title = models.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        blank=False,
        null=False,
        help_text='Overwrites the default title',
    )

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel("custom_title"),
    ]

    def get_context(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """Adding custom stuff to our context."""
        context = super().get_context(request, *args, **kwargs)

        context["categories"] = BlogCategory.objects.all()
        if request.GET.get('category'):
            context["posts"] = AddStory.objects.live().public().filter(
                categories__slug__in=[request.GET.get('category')])
        else:
            context["posts"] = AddStory.objects.live().public()
        # context["all_posts"] = AddStory.objects.live().public()
        all_posts = AddStory.objects.live().public().order_by('-first_published_at')
        if request.GET.get('tag', None):
            tags = request.GET.get('tag')
            all_posts = all_posts.filter(tags__slug__in=[tags])

        context["posts"] = all_posts
        return context


class BlogPageTag(TaggedItemBase):
    content_object = ParentalKey(
        'AddStory',
        related_name='tagged_items',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )


class AddStory(Page):
    """Blog detail page."""

    custom_title = models.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        blank=False,
        null=False,
        help_text='Overwrites the default title',
    )
    blog_image = models.ForeignKey(
        "wagtailimages.Image",
        blank=False,
        null=True,
        related_name="+",
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
    )

    content = StreamField(
        [

            ("full_richtext", blocks.RichtextBlock()),
            ("simple_richtext", blocks.SimpleRichtextBlock()),
            ("Add_video", blocks.VideoRichtextBlock()),
            ('video', InlineVideoBlock()),

        ],
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
    tags = ClusterTaggableManager(through=BlogPageTag, blank=True)
    categories = ParentalManyToManyField("blog.BlogCategory", blank=True)
    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel("custom_title"),
        ImageChooserPanel("blog_image"),
        StreamFieldPanel("content"),
        FieldPanel('tags'),
        MultiFieldPanel(
            [
                FieldPanel("categories", widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple),

            ],
            heading="Categories"
        ),

    ]
    #Exposing Custom Page Fields/content
    api_fileds = [
      APIField('content'),
      APIField('custom_title'),
      APIField('blog_image'),
    ]

class VideoBlogPage(AddStory):
    """A video subclassed page."""

    template = "blog/video_blog_page.html"

    youtube_video_id = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel("custom_title"),
        ImageChooserPanel("blog_image"),
        # MultiFieldPanel(
        #     [
        #         InlinePanel("blog_authors", label="Author", min_num=1, max_num=4)
        #     ],
        #     heading="Author(s)"
        # ),
        MultiFieldPanel(
            [
                FieldPanel("categories", widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)
            ],
            heading="Categories"
        ),
        FieldPanel("youtube_video_id"),
        StreamFieldPanel("content"),
    ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found my answer, those custom fields was exposing in details page. To get all details in one URL you can short like this
`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v2/pages/?type=blog.AddStory&fields=*`
it will expose all fields but if you want like only content & tags make your URL like this
`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v2/pages/?type=blog.AddStory&fields=content,tags`

Answer (score 1):

Per the [docs](https://docs.wagtail.org/en/stable/advanced_topics/api/v2/usage.html#fields):

> By default, only a subset of the available fields are returned in the
> response. The ?fields parameter can be used to both add additional
> fields to the response and remove default fields that you know you
> won’t need.

Try adding `?fields=*` to the url you are using to retrieve your page data.